# Camera won't follow sprite

Tags: swift, camera, sprite-kit, skcameranode

I am trying to make a game on swift SpriteKit (an RPG more specifically). I am having an issue with making the camera follow my character. So far all that happens is the camera appears off screen and you can't even see the character. Thanks!

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
     let cam = SKCameraNode()
     let james = SKSpriteNode()
     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
          self.anchorPoint = .zero
          var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image-3")
          background.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: 1000);
          background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
          addChild(background)
          view.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

          self.camera = cam

          let james = Player()
          james.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
          james.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
          james.zPosition = 1

          self.addChild(james)

          }
    override func didSimulatePhysics() {
         self.camera!.position = james.position
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to add the camera into the scene.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add camera to your scene.  I would recommend making camera a child of James so that it always follows James

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
     let cam = SKCameraNode()
     let james = SKSpriteNode()
     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
          self.anchorPoint = .zero
          var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image-3")
          background.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: 1000);
          background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
          addChild(background)
          view.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

          self.camera = cam

          let james = Player()
          james.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
          james.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
          james.zPosition = 1
          James.addChild(cam)
          self.addChild(james)

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any physics happening in the code you pasted. So likely `didSimulatePhysics` isn't getting called. try moving the `self.camera!.position = james.position` to the update function.

> edit

a lot of trouble lately seems to stem from the fact that the scene is being paused by default. try setting...

```
self.isPaused = false
```

inside

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView)
```

and putting abreak point on

```
self.camera!.position = james.position
```

to ensure that it is getting called

Comment: So I changed "override func didSimulatePhysics()" to "override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) and nothing has changed. Im not sure if thats what you meant though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: that's well outside the scope of this question. You can research debugging here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html . In the meantime just try the setting isPaused = false and see if that works

Comment: That did nothing